# Get data from "https://realtruck.com/p/rugged-ridge-floor-mats/" using Python Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get data from "https://realtruck.com/p/rugged-ridge-floor-mats/"
but the problem is they change the layout. 
now I try to get the DropDown list.

[image]

problem: the list is flexible maybe 5 lists at a time, 10 lists we don't know.
So I want flexible for loop according to the dropdown list.

Here is my previous code:
This is the static code I want it as a dynamics

```
 for year in years: 
      yield ... 
      make_arr  

      for make in make_arr:     
         yield ...      
         models_arr     

         for model in models_arr:           
           yield ...            
           body_arr 
            for body in body_arr:       
                yield ...
                colors_arr                  
                for color in colors_arr:    
                    yield ...
```

Comment: That looks more like pseudo code than [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The lists are dynamic (except from the years) and they data is populated using XHR call.

```
HTTP POST https://uwp.thiecommerce.com/uwp-v3/rt/ordercontrols/rugged-ridge-floor-mats
```

The post payload include your the user previous selections. Example

```
{"year":2018,"makeSlug":"chevy"}
```

So you need to loop over the years and and start invoking XHR calls. Inside this loop you need to nest more loops for every sub category.

something like:

```
for years in [2017,2018] # more years goes here
    #get the year Make list
    for make in makes:
        #get the make Model list
        for model in models:
            # get the model body list
            for body in bodies:
                #  call https://uwp.thiecommerce.com/uwp-v3/rt/recs/similar/? 
                        makeSlug=chevy&modelSlug=silverado- 
                        1500&year=2017&bodySlug=crew-cab&productLineSlug=rugged- 
                        ridge-floor-mats
                # and you will have the data
```